# Relative date org mode agenda search no longer working

Tags: org-mode

After updating my Emacs packages today (2023-01-04), I can't get correct results for relative date searches against org-mode fields such as `DEADLINE` anymore. (The last time I updated before today was in October 2022.) Here is the simplest demo of the issue:

2. `C-c a M` to open the agenda search (per "[Matching tags and properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html)")
3. Search for `DEADLINE<"<+7d>"`

**Expected results**: see TODO tasks where the deadline is set, and is less than 7 days in the future. *This has worked in the past.*

**Actual results**: see a lot of TODO tasks, but only ones with no DEADLINE. This is weird for two reasons: (1) I don't know why tasks with no DEADLINE value show up; and (2) I don't know why tasks due e.g. today aren't showing up.

I also tried these workarounds:

- `DEADLINE={.+}&DEADLINE<="<+7d>"` returns no TODOs
- `DEADLINE={.+}&DEADLINE>"<+7d>"` returns... maybe every todo with a deadline? It definitely includes tasks due today.

I'm a bit stumped. Did the date matching logic change at some point? Is the relative date something besides `today` now? Is there a dependent library I need to check/reinstall?

(I'm using org-mode 9.6 with Emacs 28.2 for MacOS.)

Comment: Maybe this was broken by https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=5d14e88c5 ?